# I can't define "client" SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm starting to work with signalR but I have an error (I have seen several answers on the web but none has helped me), I have the following files:

**GenteHub.cs**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

    namespace EjemploSignal
    {
        public class GenteHub:Hub
        {
            [HubMethodName("noti")]
            public static void llenarDatos()
            {
                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GenteHub>();
                context.Clients.All.updateDatos();
            }
        }
    }
```

**enlace.js**

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.genteHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        cargarDatos();
    });

    $.notificationHub.client.updateDatos = function () {
        cargarDatos();
    };

    function cargarDatos() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/lista",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta2) {
                console.log("Respuesta", respuesta2);

            }
        });
    }
```

**Layout.html (script references)**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/enlace.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have 2 errors, the first one is in the console:

[image]

According to several examples is because I don't put the name of the class and others is that I must put the name of `[HubMethodName]` (I already put both and have the same error)

The second error I get in the Network:

```
if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }
```

Which is according to why the file `hub` is not being generated, because:

- The correct order of the files is not being placed (When I have them
  in order "jquery, jquery signal, hub")
- It must be placed or not the    symbol (~) (The bad thing is that I
  put it on and remove it and the    error still persists)

Someone recommends me delete `$.` from

```
$.notificationHub.client.updateDatos = function () {
        cargarDatos();
};
```

to avoid the first error and it works but when I loaded the page, `cargarDatos()` from `$.connection.hub.start().done(function ()` deploys correctly but when I add a new record in the database nothing happens.

What's my mistakes in this code?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`. So where are you accessing client? `$.notificationHub.client`...so `$.notificationHub` is undefined. Did you mean just `notificationHub`?

Comment: @FrankerZ yes, in that line is the first error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `notificationHub.client` instead of `$.notificationHub.client`.So write your `enlace.js` code as follows:

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.genteHub;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
     cargarDatos();
});

notificationHub.client.updateDatos = function () { // not $.notificationHub, its notificationHub
        cargarDatos();
};

function cargarDatos() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/lista",
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (respuesta2) {
                console.log("Respuesta", respuesta2);

       }
    });
}
```

> when I add a new record in the database nothing happens.

It will not call automatically whenever you add records into database. You have to call it manually after adding records to the database as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAddRecordMethod(YourRecord yourRecord)
{
    // Your adding record code here

    HubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<GenteHub>();
    context.Clients.All.updateDatos();
}
```

Comment: I have the.js file in that way but `cargarDatos()` in start doesn't show me anything in console.

I don't have any method to save the record, I add a new record directly in SQL SERVER (SSMS) with the hope that when add a new record in SSMS the hub can update or do something what I expect (again I`m new with this and I don't know if this is possible)

Comment: No no! When you add record into SQL server using SSMS then how SignalR will know that?

Comment: "I have the.js file in that way but cargarDatos() in start doesn't show me anything in console"-Can you give me team viewer id and pass to check please?

Comment: 1 063 653 658/
5211